# : No such file or directory: /dev/fd/62 Error when I use >(...)

Tags: bash, substitution, tee

I have script

```
#!/bin/bash
exec &> >(tee file.log)
some command
some command
some command
some command
```

I add comand `exec &> >(tee file.log)` to save output and still the outpun in CMD
When I run it I get error `: No such file or directory: /dev/fd/62`
if I write `some command | tee file.log` all work properly, but I don't want to add it to every comand.
The comand `exec &>file.log` is work, but it doesn't write in CMD.
Bash version is GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
What the problem?

Comment: Which bash version are you using? Please show the output of `bash --version`.

Comment: Sounds like your script has carriage returns

Comment: @KamilCuk Bash version is GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: And yes, this sounds like you have CRLFs, aka DOS newlines. `dos2unix` is your friend (or in vim, `:set fileformat=unix`). A CR character sends the cursor back to the front of the line, thus your error message starting with a `:`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks. dos2unix helped